# Training a single linear neuron for regression using batch gradient descent

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning

I'm trying to use gradient descent to train some weights however I'm not having much success.
I started off with a learning rate `lr` of 0.01 and my cost was actually sky-rocketing upwards which surprised me. I can only assume it wasn't small enough to find any local minima's. Changing it to 0.0000000000001 allowed it to stabilise and decrease slowly enough.

Iteration 998 | Cost: 2444.995584

Iteration 999 | Cost: 2444.995577

Iteration 1000 | Cost: 2444.995571

Final weights: 5.66633309647e-07 | 4.32179246434e-09

However either something is wrong with theses weights or how I plot them:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def gradient_descent(x, y, w, lr, m, iter):
    xTrans = x.transpose()
    for i in range(iter):
        prediction = np.dot(x, w)
        loss = prediction - y
        cost = np.sum(loss ** 2) / m

        print("Iteration %d | Cost: %f" % (i + 1, cost))

        gradient = np.dot(xTrans, loss) / m     # avg gradient

        w = w - lr * gradient   # update the weight vector

    return w

# generate data from uniform distribution -10. +10 and linear function
x = np.arange(1, 200, 2)
d = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, x.size)
y = .4 * x + 3 + d

# number of training samples
m = y.size

# add a column of ones for bias values
it = np.ones(shape=(m, 2))
it[:, 1] = x

m, n = np.shape(it)

# initialise weights to 0
w = np.zeros(n)

iter = 1000             # number of iterations
lr = 0.0000000000001    # learning rate / alpha

trained_w = gradient_descent(it, y, w, lr, m, iter)
result = trained_w[1] * x + trained_w[0]    # linear plot of our predicted function
print("Final weights: %s | %s" % (trained_w[1], trained_w[0]))

plt.plot(x, y, 'gx')
plt.plot(x, result)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overcompensated. The learning rate is so small here that it will take billions of iterations to converge. Set it to something smaller than `0.01`, but larger than what you have now.

It worked just fine for me with an alpha of `0.0001`.

Comment: Wow thanks, as simple as that. I probably should have decremented it slowly rather than jump to such a ridiculously small number. Makes sense when I think about it, it's stepping down the gradient so slowly it can't get anywhere.

Comment: No problem! It's an easy mistake to make.